# <Select> on change doesn´t work with value change through .val()

Tags: jquery

```
$('#changeRows').on('change', function(){
    var changedValue = $('#changeRows').val();
    alert("This is my value: "+changedValue);
    //do my stuff
}

setTimeout(function() {
    $('#changeRows').val("<?=$contentData['rows'];?>");
}, 1500);
```

How can i get this to work like expected? The value gets changed, but the on change isn´t called...

Comment: Because onchange only is triggered when the USER changes the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change event is fired when the value is changed through **GUI not through code**. Although you can fire the change event using `.trigger("change")` or `change()`

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XG8A6/)

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#changeRows').val("<?=$contentData['rows'];?>").change();
}, 1500);
```

Answer (score 1):

The change event will be fired only if a user action caused the change

You need to trigger it manually in case of programtic changes, you can use [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) or [.trigger('change')](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#changeRows').val("<?=$contentData['rows'];?>").change();
}, 1500);
```

Comment: ouh i´m stupid...i know the .change(), but didn´t need to use it til now...thank you both very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with jquery's body on change:-

$('body','#changeRows').on('change', function (e) {

});

Or you can opt for the following jquery's live change if your elements in dom are being made dynamically:

$('.changeRows').live('change', function() {

});

Comment: additional: I thought one shouldn´t use .live() anymore. it´s deprecated...or am I wrong? But thanks.